# Copyright on bottom of chat page needs to be updated

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, copyright, footer

The bottom of the [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) page currently says:

> site design / logo © 2011 stack overflow internet services, inc

Since the name of the company has been changed to *Stack Exchange, Inc.*, the line needs to be updated.  This is similar to the problem discussed in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82744/footer-is-wrong, but this applies to the chat page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess nostalgia doesn't count as an excuse, hm? Oh well. Fixed now, thanks :)